# How to tell the Firefox start page to use specific images?

Tags: html, http, firefox

Using a completely fresh install of Firefox, I see a start page with these icons/pages:

[Firefox start page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeqzy.png)

Hovering over the "Customize Firefox" box, the image changes to this:

[Hovering over Customize Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6RQ1.png)

The normal behavior of Firefox is to create some sort of screenshot for the start page images.  However, it looks like there might be a way to control the image that appears as well as what appears when hovering over each image.

What HTML tag(s) or HTTP header(s) is/are required to get customization of images on the Firefox start page?

Update:

Digging around a bit, I see the following HTML for the "Get Firefox for Android" option:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="newtab-cell">
  <div class="newtab-site" draggable="true" type="history" pinned="true">
    <span class="newtab-sponsored">SPONSORED</span>
    <a class="newtab-link" title="Get Firefox for Android http://mzl.la/1Dls1DC" href="http://mzl.la/1Dls1DC">
      <span class="newtab-thumbnail placeholder"></span>
      <span class="newtab-thumbnail thumbnail" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://tiles-cloudfront.cdn.mozilla.net/images/a15c0403863847aef5943a6272cd992335f330f9.59611.png&quot;);"></span>
      <span class="newtab-thumbnail enhanced-content" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://tiles-cloudfront.cdn.mozilla.net/images/ef8c1bab9b54c37fddbd8eeb15faf733571fc9f9.64436.png&quot;);"></span>
      <span class="newtab-title">Get Firefox for Android</span>
    </a>
    <input title="Unpin this site" class="newtab-control newtab-control-pin" type="button" />
    <input title="Remove this site" class="newtab-control newtab-control-block" type="button" />
    <span class="newtab-suggested"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

A "normal" entry looks more like this:

```
<a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="newtab-link" title="Twilio Console https://www.twilio.com/console" href="https://www.twilio.com/console">
  <span class="newtab-thumbnail placeholder"></span>
  <span class="newtab-thumbnail thumbnail" style="background-image: url(&quot;moz-page-thumb://thumbnail/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.twilio.com%2Fconsole&amp;revision=4346&quot;);"></span>
  <span class="newtab-thumbnail enhanced-content"></span>
  <span class="newtab-title">twilio.com</span>
</a>
```

The `newtab-thumbnail thumbnail` span appears to be how the on hover is working and the `newtab-thumbnail enhanced-content` span is the non-hover image that is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to this question is:  No.  There is currently no way to affect the images that get displayed by Firefox on the New Tab page.

After doing quite a bit more digging, I finally figured out what is going on.  Mozilla calls the page the "New Tab page" not the "Start page".  Mozilla calls the tiles "Directory Links" and there are a bunch of rules regarding what can be included in the Directory Links Provider:

http://gecko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/browser/browser/DirectoryLinksProvider.html

There are two configuration options of note `browser.newtabpage.directory.source` and `browser.newtabpage.directory.ping`.  A Directory Links Provider must point at https://tiles.services.mozilla.com/ as the base URI.  This policy is enforced by the browser itself.  An example provider is:

https://tiles.services.mozilla.com/v3/links/fetch/en-US/release

Which shows what the user sees in a fresh install.  There is no way to provide metadata or such via a HTML page or Javascript to provide hints for a New Tab page.  The New Tab page lives in isolation and has strict rules built in to prevent user tracking (e.g. no cookies are sent).  I'd wager a good part of the reasoning is user privacy and browser security.  Imagine the ability to track user habits via a New Tab page or repeatedly infect a machine via a bug in a JPEG library every time a new tab is opened.  It's a bit disappointing because the thumbnails that Firefox generates for most websites look pretty terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing since I don't definitively know if this is true, but it looks like the new tab tile data is being pulled via [OpenGraph](http://ogp.me/) metadata tags. For example, on the MDN page:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/static/img/opengraph-logo.dc4e08e2f6af.png">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Mozilla Developer Network">
<meta property="og:description" content="The Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) provides information about Open Web technologies including HTML, CSS, and APIs for both Web sites and HTML5 Apps. It also documents Mozilla products, like Firefox OS.">
<meta property="og:title" content="Mozilla Developer Network">
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could check this out by typing

```
about:config
```

I did not crawl completly through it but i already found browser.newtabpage.directory.source

Maybe that is what you are looking for,
 just a quick thought tho, no guaranty for the right track here.